# Construct a bijection such that $\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{k(l)}}{k(l)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following series: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$, with $a_{k}=\cfrac{(-1)^k}{k}$. I know that the series converges to $-log(2)$ and that it is not absolutely convergent, thus the series is conditionally convergent.
 I now have to construct a bijection $b_l=a_{k(l)}$ in $\mathbb{N} $ \ $\{0\}$
such that the series $\sum_{l\geq1}b_{l}=\sum_{l\geq1}a_{k(l)}$ is convergent with limit equal to $0$.
I know that because $a_{k}$ is not absolutely convergent that we can use the rearrangement theorem to prove this, so it would be something like:
$$log(2)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}....$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{56}...$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}-1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{3}+...$$
$$=1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5}=0$$
I tried constructing a function to show this, this is what I came up with:

$a_{k(l)}=-l$, when $l$ is odd
 $a_{k(l)}=l-1$ when $l$ is even
I really don't know if this is the correct way to do this, can someone help me with this?

Comment: You are only allowed to switch the order of terms in this business, but you are attempting to modify terms themselves in the second line. For instance, you are replacing $-\frac{1}{2}$ by two terms $\frac{1}{2} + (-1)$, none of which are in the original sequence $(a_n)$. So this approach does not work.

Comment: See snapshot 1 at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RearrangingTheAlternatingHarmonicSeries/

Comment: $1-\frac1{2}-\frac1{4}-\frac1{6}-\frac1{8}+\frac1{3}-\frac1{10}-\frac1{12}-\frac1{14}-\frac1{16}+\frac1{5}-\frac1{18}-\frac1{20}-\frac1{22}-\frac1{24}+\frac1{7}-\frac1{26}-\frac1{28}-\frac1{30}-\frac1{32}+\frac1{9}-\ldots$ Is this enough to recognize the pattern?

Comment: I assume the pattern is 1 positive term and 4 negative terms to make it converge to zero. But what is $k(l)$?

Comment: The example in the comments above is actually for $-a_n = (-1)^{n-1}/n$. In your case, you should be able to read out $k(l)$'s from $$ \tfrac{(-1)^{k(1)}}{k(1)}+\tfrac{(-1)^{k(2)}}{k(2)}+\tfrac{(-1)^{k(3)}}{k(3)}+\cdots=-1+\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{6}+\tfrac{1}{8}-\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{10}+\tfrac{1}{12}+\tfrac{1}{14}+\tfrac{1}{16}-\cdots.$$ (*Hint:* Read out the denominators! *Hint 2:* You need not provide some analytic formula generating $k(l)$. It is enough to explain a way how $k$ is constructed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rearrangement

\begin{align*}
&(k(1), k(2), k(3) \cdots) \\
&\hspace{3em} = (
\underbrace{1, 2, 4, 6, 8}, \ 
\underbrace{3, 10, 12, 14, 16}, \ 
\cdots, \
\underbrace{2k-1, 8k-6, 8k-4, 8k-2, 8k}, \
\cdots)
\end{align*}

mentioned in the comment works because we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{l=1}^{5n} a_{k(l)}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{8k-6} + \frac{1}{8k-4} + \frac{1}{8k-2} + \frac{1}{8k} - \frac{1}{2k-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(H_{4n} - H_{2n}) - \frac{1}{2}(H_{2n} - H_n) \\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \quad \frac{1}{2}\log 2 - \frac{1}{2}\log 2 = 0,
\end{align*}

where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$-th harmonic number. But this is rather a clever tinkering very specific to the given structure of the particular sequence $a_n = (-1)^{n-1}/n$ and may not easy to come up with.

So let me give the following general theorem showing the general idea.

> **Riemann Rearrangement Theorem.** Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be conditionally convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a rearrangement $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)} = \alpha$.

Here is a brief idea: Due to the conditional convergence, the sum of positive terms of $(a_n)$ and that of negative terms of $(a_n)$ diverge separately. Then we can group positive terms and negative terms cleverly and arrange them in such a way that (1) positive groups and negative groups appear alternate and that (2) the resulting partial sum oscillates and slowly dampenes toward $\alpha$.

The proof is divided into several steps.

**Step 1. (Construction)** Let $(a_k^{+})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be the subsequence of $(a_n)$ consisting of all non-negative terms of $(a_n)$.<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAHAI.png)</sup> Similarly, let $(a_k^{-})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be the subsequence of $(a_n)$ consisting of all negative terms of $(a_n)$. Then we know that both partial sums

$$s_k^{+} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i^{+}
\quad \text{and} \quad
s_k^{-} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i^{-}$$

diverge to $+\infty$. Now pick $(m_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and $(n_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:<sup>[2]</sup>

- $m_j$ is the smallest natural number $m$ such that $s_m^{+} \geq \sqrt{j} +\alpha$.
- $n_j$ is the smallest natural number $n$ such that $s_n^{-} \leq -\sqrt{j} $.

For instance, the following graph shows first few terms of $(m_j)$'s and $(n_j)$'s corresponding to the sequence $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ and $\alpha = 1$.

$\hspace{2em}$ [image: Example of $m_j$'s and $n_j$'s]

Finally, we concatenate all the following finite sequences

$$ \color{blue}{( a_k^{+} )_{k=1}^{m_1}}, \quad
\color{red}{( a_k^{-} )_{k=1}^{n_1}}, \quad
\color{blue}{( a_k^{+} )_{k=m_1 + 1}^{m_2}}, \quad
\color{red}{( a_k^{-} )_{k=n_1 + 1}^{n_2}}, \quad
\color{blue}{( a_k^{+} )_{k=m_2 + 1}^{m_3}}, \quad
\color{red}{( a_k^{-} )_{k=n_2 + 1}^{n_3}}, \quad
\cdots
$$

to form an infinite sequence $(a'_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.<sup>[3]</sup> Since each term of $(a_n)$ appears exactly once in this newly formed sequence, there exists $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $a'_n = a_{\sigma(n)}$.

**Step 2. (Some observations)** Then it is easy to check that

- $s_{m_j}^{+} \in [\sqrt{j} + \alpha, \sqrt{j} + \alpha + a_{m_j}^{+})$ whenever $m_j \geq 2$. The lower bound is clear from how $m_j$ is chosen. For the upper bound, by the minimality of $m_j$ we have $s_{m_j - 1}^{+} < \sqrt{j} + \alpha$. Adding $a_{m_j}^+$ to both sides provides the desired upper bound.
- $s_{n_j}^{-} \in (-\sqrt{j} + a_{n_j}^{-}, -\sqrt{j}]$ whenever $n_j \geq 2$. The reasoning is similar to the previous one, so we skip this.
- For $n \in [m_j + n_j, m_{j+1} + n_{j+1}]$, we have

  $$ \min \left\{ s_{m_j}^+ + s_{n_j}^-, s_{m_{j+1}}^+ + s_{n_{j+1}}^- \right\} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a'_k \leq s_{m_{j+1}}^+ + s_{n_j}^- $$

**Step 3. (Proof)** Now we can combine all these estimates to provide a proof. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and pick $J$ such that all the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $\sqrt{j+1} - \sqrt{j} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $j \geq J$,
2. $m_j \geq 2$ and $n_j \geq 2$ for all $j \geq J$,
3. $|a^+_{m_j}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a^-_{n_j}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $j \geq J$.

Then for each $n \geq N = m_J + n_J$, pick $j \geq J$ such that $n \in [m_j + n_j, m_{j+1} + n_{j+1}]$. Then by Step 2,

$$ - \tfrac{1}{2}\epsilon
\leq \min\{ a_{n_j}^{-}, a_{n_{j+1}}^{-} \}
\leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a'_k \right) - \alpha
\leq \sqrt{j+1}-\sqrt{j} + a_{m_{j+1}}^{+}
\leq \epsilon. $$

Therefore we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a'_n = \alpha$ as desired. ////

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAHAI.png) In other words, $a^{+}_k = a_{n_k}$ where $n_k$ denotes the $k$-th non-negative term appearing in $(a_n)$. But we will never care about the position $(n_k)$, so you can simply forget about $(n_k)$ and proceed.

[2] You can replace $\sqrt{j}$ by any sequence $b_j$ which increases to $+\infty$ and satisfies $b_{j+1} - b_j \to 0$.

[3] When $m_j = m_{j+1}$, the corresponding sequence $( a_k^{+} )_{k=m_j + 1}^{m_{j+1}}$ is considered empty, thus providing no contribution to the construction of $(a_n')$. Similar comment applies when $n_j = n_{j+1}$.

Comment: I programmed exactly this algorithm to discover the pattern (so it wasn't difficult), and then, I proved it with the partial sums.